# how to show override hover state i

Tags: html, css, hover

All
i want to set hover state active on mobile device

I have 2 scenarios    **when user use website on desktop ,when he hover on before image after image will replace by before** .

But when user **access website using mobile only after image is shown to user**

My destop is completey implemeted but don't know how to achieve mobile version

[DESTOP Example](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-image-swap-on-hover)

```css
    .card {
        width: 130px;
        height: 195px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 50px;
    }
    .card .img-top {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .card:hover .img-top {
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/images/card-back.jpg" alt="Card Back">
        <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/images/card-front.jpg" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">
```

Comment: have you tried media queries? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a media-query that targets a mobile device width (480px) and you should be good to go. To see this in action expand the demo below and adjust your browser width accordingly.

```css
.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}

.card .img-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .card .img-top {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .card:hover .img-top {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/images/card-back.jpg" alt="Card Back">
  <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/images/card-front.jpg" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">
</div>
```

Comment: That's strange. I've changed nothing in the code since then. Is it possible you might've altered it on your system?

Comment: Yes Carl Edwars i will see it again deeply and then share my finding with you thanks for your quick response